# How to assign input radio value to a textarea content?

Tags: javascript

I have this form:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" id="option-1" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to John"><label for="option-1">John</label>
<input type="radio" id="option-2" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Maria"><label for="option-2">Maria</label>
<input type="radio" id="option-3" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Kennedy"><label for="option-3">Kennedy</label>
<input type="radio" id="option-4" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Adam"><label for="option-4">Adam</label>
</form>
```

And I have this other form with an `textarea`:

```
<form>
<textarea id="textarea-field" placeholder='Type your message here...' required/>
</form>
```

I would like to know if there is any simple way to assign the `value` of the chosen `input` inside the `textarea` content right when user click one of these input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more `feasible` and **easiest** way would be do this way by making sure you assign an `id` to your form which will ensure that you are only `selecting` `Input[type=radio]` from that form and not every `input` on your page.

Also use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to assign a value to your `textArea`. Using `innerHTML` is **not** recommended.

We need to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to loop through all the input which we will find using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function (which returns all nodes list) and then use we can [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to make sure that we listen to `change` events on your input and assign the value of the `checked` radio `button` to your `textArea`

**Live Demo:**

```js
//get all radio buttons
let getRadios = document.querySelectorAll('#myForm > input[type="radio"]');
//get text area
let getTextArea = document.querySelector('#textarea-field');

//Loop through the radio button
getRadios.forEach(function(radio) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
    getTextArea.textContent = this.value //assign value to textArea
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" id="option-1" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to John"><label for="option-1">John</label>
  <input type="radio" id="option-2" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Maria"><label for="option-2">Maria</label>
  <input type="radio" id="option-3" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Kennedy"><label for="option-3">Kennedy</label>
  <input type="radio" id="option-4" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Adam"><label for="option-4">Adam</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <textarea id="textarea-field" placeholder='Type your message here...' required>
  </textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give each of your input a class purely for this script below it should work.

```
<script>
 // GIVE EACH OF YOUR INPUTS A CLASS OF .input
 // THEN ADD THIS SCRIPT
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input').click(function(e) {
        var text = $( this ).val();
        $('#textarea-field').val( text );
 
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea-field');

radios.forEach(radio => {

  radio.addEventListener('change', ({
    target
  }) => textarea.innerHTML = target.value);

});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="option-1" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to John"><label for="option-1">John</label>
  <input type="radio" id="option-2" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Maria"><label for="option-2">Maria</label>
  <input type="radio" id="option-3" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Kennedy"><label for="option-3">Kennedy</label>
  <input type="radio" id="option-4" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Adam"><label for="option-4">Adam</label>
  <textarea id="textarea-field" placeholder='Type your message here...' required></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a Custom Class to input where you want to put Radio Button

The Code below Gets the Value of clicked input radio button and sets in the TextArea Field.

```js
$('.radiobuttoninput').click(function() {
  $('#textarea-field').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="radiobuttoninput" type="radio" id="option-1" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to John"><label for="option-1">John</label>
  <input class="radiobuttoninput" type="radio" id="option-2" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Maria"><label for="option-2">Maria</label>
  <input class="radiobuttoninput" type="radio" id="option-3" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Kennedy"><label for="option-3">Kennedy</label>
  <input class="radiobuttoninput" type="radio" id="option-4" name="name" value="Hello! I would like to talk to Adam"><label for="option-4">Adam</label>
</form>

<br>
<form>
  <textarea id="textarea-field" placeholder='Type your message here...' required> </textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any libraries then you can also use vanilla to do this. Nothing to explain here so I will just show you.

HTML file:

```
<form  name="form">
        <input type="radio" name="rate" value="1"/>i am 1
        <input type="radio" name="rate" value="2"/>i am 2
        <input type="radio" name="rate" value="3"/>i am 3
 </form>
        
  <textarea value="" id="ta"></textarea>
```

You don't need id for the form or radio boxes. Just declare a name. That would do the trick.

JavaScript file:

```
document.form.onclick = function() {
var v = document.form.rate.value;

var t = document.getElementById("ta");
t.value = v;
}
```

Let me know if it worked.